# UITableview takes multiple scrolling attempts before scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that uses a custom cell. My issue is that scrolling is unresponsive to my first and often second and third attempts. I almost always have to swipe up multiple times before it will actually scroll down. It scrolls smoothly once it gets moving, but it takes multiple scrolls to get it started again once it stops.

```swift
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardNameLabel: UILabel!

    func configure(withItem card: Networking.Card) {

    }
}
```

```swift
class collectionTableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var cardData: [Networking.Card] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cardData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        cell.cardNameLabel.text = cardData[indexPath.row].cfDisplayName
        return cell
    }
}
```

```swift
class TableVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionTable: UITableView!
var dataSource: collectionTableDataSource!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = collectionTableDataSource()
    collectionTable.dataSource = dataSource

    Networking.shared.getCardsForUser(user: "1") { (response) in
            self.dataSource.cardData = response
            self.collectionTable.reloadData()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I isolated the issue to a timer on the previous view controller. The timer runs every 5 seconds and makes a networking request. I fixed the problem by invalidating the timer before segue to the view controller with the UITableview. Now scrolling runs smoothly.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "firstSegue" {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is at this part of your code:

```
Networking.shared.getCardsForUser(user: "1") { (response) in
    self.dataSource.cardData = response
    self.collectionTable.reloadData()
}
```

Please, make sure that the completion handler of your async request is performed on the main queue. It's required because you're trying to reload `UITableView`. Any UI-related work must be done at `DispatchQueue.main`

So you can try the following:

```
Networking.shared.getCardsForUser(user: "1") { response in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dataSource.cardData = response
        self.collectionTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, adding DispatchQueue.main.async did not solve my specifc issue. The getCardsForUser function occurs during viewdidload() and the scrolling issue persists after load takes place.

Comment: So what if you wait for, let's say, 10 seconds before the first attempt of scrolling. Does this issue remain in this case? Just want to make sure if it's related to whether the request has finished or not.

Comment: You can also check the bottom "Debug area" in Xcode and see if there are some warnings. Maybe it's something wrong with layout and it causes the initial lag.

Comment: Yes, the issue still occurs after waiting 10 seconds. And the request is pretty instantaneous so it doesn't seem related to the getCardsForUser function. Maybe worth noting, very slow scrolling works OK, but quick swipes cause the table to freeze for a second or two before jumping to the bottom.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with `UIGestureRecognizer`s that you use? Maybe the views' hierarchy is built so some other view reacts to the gestures instead of letting the `UITableView` to perform scrolling? You can try to create your `UITableView` on an empty `UIViewController` and make sure that it works.

Comment: Also the problem might be with: 1) Implementation of `UITableViewCell` - try to use the most dumb cell as possible and check if it's scrolling; 2) Content height calculation - maybe some layout issues lead `UITableView` to be unsure about cells' height so it sets it to 0 and doesn't want to scroll. To check this case I would temporary set some hard-coded height for the cells.

Comment: If you think that my answer and/or my comments were helpful, please, upvote some of them. I would appreciate it :)